# angular event handler with named function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have an event handler attached to an input element with ng-change attribute.  When I assign the handler with an unnamed function, the button click works.  When I assign the handler with a named function, the browser will try to resolve all the parameters in the named function during the load time.  It seems the javascript event handler has to be declared with an unnamed function.  What is the difference between these two?  Thanks.

```js
//this doesn't fire the event handler
//vm.facilityChanged = facilityChanged(vm, fsrFactory);

//this works
vm.facilityChanged = function() {
  vm.postStatus = undefined;
  vm.services = undefined;
  vm.roles = undefined;
  vm.services = fsrFactory.service().query({
      FacilityID: vm.facility
    })
    .$promise.then(
      function(data) {
        vm.services = data;
      });
}

function facilityChanged(vm, fsrFactory) {
  vm.postStatus = undefined;
  vm.services = undefined;
  vm.roles = undefined;
  vm.services = fsrFactory.service().query({
      FacilityID: vm.facility
    })
    .$promise.then(
      function(data) {
        vm.services = data;
      });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
vm.facilityChanged = function() {
    ...
}
```

This makes `vm.facilityChanged` a reference to the anonymous function.

```
vm.facilityChanged = facilityChanged(vm, fsrFactory);
```

However, this *calls* the named function, `facilityChanged`, with the variables `vm` and `fsrFactory`. What you want to do is *reference* the named function with `vm.facilityChanged` like you did with the anonymous function.

```
vm.facilityChanged = facilityChanged;

function facilityChanged(vm, fsrFactory) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hey, how do I pass the vm and fsrFactory from the controller to the named functions?  The vm and fsrFactory are all undefined in the named function.  Thanks.